# Firebase (Firechat) "Route not found." error

Tags: firebase

I have been trying to use the firebase fire chat, it works using the default demo url (http://firechat.firebaseapp.com). However, as soon as I change it to my URL it does not work, even though I have enabled twitter login, and I have twitter authentication working on another firebase app. The error message I get is the following:

```
{"error":{"code":"ROUTE_NOT_FOUND","message":"Route not found."}}
```

Any idea?

source: https://github.com/firebase/firechat

Comment: What URL are you using?

Comment: See [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [creating an mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Since Firechat doesn't do any routing, this is much more likely to be related to your third party integration (e.g. Angular)

Comment: I am using elchungo.firebaseio.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, in the Twitter app settings, the following option was ticked. So, I untucked it and it is now working

```
Enable Callback Locking (It is recommended to enable callback locking to ensure apps cannot overwrite the callback url)
```

Answer (score 1):

The twitter callback url for your app should be:
https://auth.firebase.com/v2/your-firebase-app-name/auth/twitter/callback

Answer (score 0):

you need to set Callback URL in https://apps.twitter.com/app/xxxxxx/settings
for example, https://auth.firebase.com/v2/xxxxxxx/auth/twitter/callback